# how to call array variable from one method into another variable

Tags: java, variables, jdbc

How do I call the variable `show[j]` and `actuate[j]` which are located in Attribute() method into xmls(). If I declare this outside I will get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`. count is a variable got from other query.

```
  void Attribute() throws SQLException{
  Statement statement3=connection.createStatement();
  String Querystring3="select Show ,actuate from rlink";
  ResultSet Attrib=statement3.executeQuery(Querystring3);
  String[] Show=new String[Count];
  String[] Actuate=new String[Count];
  while(Attrib.next()){
  Show[j]=Attrib.getString(1);
  Actuate[j]=Attrib.getString(2);
  j++;
  }
 for(i=0;i<Count;i++){
   System.out.println(Show[i]+"   "+Actuate[i]);
}
}

  void xmlS() throws IOException{
  Element child = doc.createElement("body");
   root.appendChild(child);
    for(i=0;i<LinkCount;i++){

         Element child1 = doc.createElement("link");


               child1.setAttributeNS(xlink,"xlink:show", Show[i]);
               child1.setAttributeNS(xlink,"xlink:actuate",Actuate[i]);

       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you don't "call" variables. You call methods and constructors - it's asking them to *do* something. You don't do that with variables.

As for how you can get access to your variables from the `xmlS` method, there are two immediate options:

- Make them *instance* variables instead of local variables, i.e. declare them as members of the class
- Pass them as parameters to `xmlS`, if you can call that method *from* the method where they're declared. (You're not doing so in the code you've shown, but you may be doing so in your real code.)

It's not obvious what your class is meant to be doing (and the method names don't help to reveal anything either), so it's unclear which is actually appropriate. If they're logically part of the state of the object, then make them instance variables. Otherwise, consider how the data should *flow* through your program. Should this data be returned from the `Attribute` method perhaps? (e.g. as a `List` of show/actuate pairs)

Comment: @user977830: I would suggest you get a *book* on learning Java. While experimentation and asking questions is good, you should really start with something which is designed to teach you Java from scratch. Stack Overflow isn't a good replacement for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. They're *local variables* in `Attribute()`, so they only exist as long as you're in a call to `Attribute()`, and you never call `xmlS()` from within `Attribute()`. You'd have to call `xmlS()` from within `Attribute()` and pass them into it as arguments.